# Display tick image on selected QMenu item

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want to show a tick item on selecting particular item from my `QMenu`.
Currently its showing the menus, but I need to keep a kick also so that next time user can know which is selected before.

```
QMenu *preferenceMenu = new QMenu();
preferenceMenu  = editMenu->addMenu(tr("&Preferences"));

QMenu *Mode1 = new QMenu();
Mode1  = preferenceMenu->addMenu(tr("&Mode 1"));
Mode1->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Menu1"), this));

QMenu *Mode2 = new QMenu();
Mode2  = preferenceMenu->addMenu(tr("&Mode 2"));
Mode2->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Menu2"), this));
Mode2->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Menu3"), this));
```

On `QAction` I call slot `slotActionTriggered(QAction* actionSelected)`.

```
void csTitleBar::slotActionTriggered(QAction* actionSelected)
{
   actionSelected->setChecked(true);
}
```

Here if I select `Menu3`, a tick also should appear right side of `Menu3` and later if I change to `Menu2`, tick should show on `Menu2` and disappear from `Menu3`.

Please give some idea, whether Qt have some default method to do it or I need to keep widget or image.

Comment: If you need a set of `QAction`s to be mutually exclusive you can use a [`QActionGroup`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have to make actions *checkable* via [`QAction::setCheckable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#checkable-prop).

```
QMenu *Mode2 = new QMenu();
Mode2  = preferenceMenu->addMenu(tr("&Mode 2"));
Mode2->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Menu2"), this));
Mode2->actions().back()->setCheckable(true);
Mode2->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Menu3"), this));
Mode2->actions().back()->setCheckable(true);
```

Also, there is no need to check actions manually in your case, marking them as checkable already does the job.

As mentioned by [@G.M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6371123/g-m), to make some of them mutually exclusive, you have to create a [`QActionGroup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html#details) for each set (`Menu2` and `Menu3` in your case). Just set the action group as the parent of the action or call `QActionGroup::addAction`.

```
  QMenu* Mode2 = new QMenu();
  QActionGroup* Mode2ActionGroup = new QActionGroup(Mode2);
  Mode2  = preferenceMenu->addMenu(tr("&Mode 2"));
  Mode2->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Menu2"), Mode2ActionGroup));
  Mode2->actions().back()->setCheckable(true);
  Mode2->addAction(new QAction(tr("&Menu3"), Mode2ActionGroup));
  Mode2->actions().back()->setCheckable(true);
```

*PS: although links redirect to Qt 5.xx documentation, solution works in both Qt 4.8 and Qt 5.xx.*